# How to handle Site Map for Multiple websites

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I have a single code base where I am running multiple websites.

For example my

```
http://www.example1.com/Example1  
http://www.example2.com/Example2  
http://www.example3.com/example3
```

In this way the links for my page will be differ for all websites.

Now problem is that how I can create site map for websites like these.

Explaination.

I have one web application project and on that web application project I have multiple events
Now I can map these events like this.

```
http://www.example1.com/Example1
http://www.example2.com/Example2
http://www.example3.com/example3
```

So my first events has urls

```
http://www.example1.com/Example1/Page1  
http://www.example1.com/Example1/Page2  
http://www.example1.com/Example1/Page3  
http://www.example1.com/Example1/Page4
```

Second one is like:

```
http://www.example2.com/Example1/Page5  
http://www.example2.com/Example1/Page7  
http://www.example2.com/Example1/Page2  
http://www.example2.com/Example1/Page6
```

Now as site map can be added to root directory so there can be only one site map. 
but I have number of domains mapped to a single IP. so how I can handle site map with multiple domains and with a single IP.
or I need to create multiple site maps and then i can submit that based on domain.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is - do you want to know where to put the sitemap.xml file, or something else?

Comment: OK, but what is your question? What do you want to know?

Comment: I updated my question with more info

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 different Sitemaps for 4 domains and keep them in the root directory of respective domain. or You can use server-side code to send the correct sitemap based on the domain name for requests to /sitemap.xml.

Refer the article: http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/multiple-domains-xml-sitemaps/

Comment: how I can use server side code to send correct sitemap. any code example.?